# How to change the colour of the all lines in tabularx?

Tags: color, tabularx

I have a `LaTeX` document, where I have a `tabularx` environment, and I need to change all lines in the table to grey. I have tried this command `\arrayrulecolor{grey}\hline`, but it changed just the colour of the bottom line, how to change them all?

Comment: `\arrayrulecolor` does not act `backwards`, only the following rules will have the new colour then , i.e. you have to use it before `tabularx` for **all** following rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\arrayrulecolor` commands sets the colour only for the following rules but not for those that were set before `\arrayrulecolor` was used.
This change is 'global' in the sense that it acts on the following rules, but not outside of the `tabular(x)` etc. environment (see the example)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tabularx}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
  \hline
  foo & foobar \tabularnewline
  \arrayrulecolor{red}
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\begin{center}
Another table with black rules
\end{center}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
  \hline
  foo & foobar \tabularnewline
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\begin{center}
Another table with red rules
\end{center}


\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
  \arrayrulecolor{red}
  \hline
  foo & foobar \tabularnewline
  \hline
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

[image]